# Want to fine tune pretrained RoBERTa, from Huggingface, on my own data for text summarization

Tags: text, pytorch, summarization, roberta-language-model

I am a beginner in this. Please help me in getting a solution.
I have used the *RobertaTokenizerFast* to tokenize the text and summary (*max_token_length* 200 and 50 respectively).
The plan is to use *RoBERTa* as the first layer. Then condense its output to match the target summary using conv2d, maxpool2d, and dense. The output of the last dense layer is a float vector. So, I have normalized the target vector, containing *long* input_ids, into *float* values (*0 to 1*). Finally, I have used *CrossEntropy* function to get the loss.

```
class Summarizer(pl.LightningModule):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.roberta = RobertaModel.from_pretrained('roberta-base', return_dict = True, is_decoder=True, use_cache=False) 
    self.convlayer = torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels=BATCH_SIZE, out_channels=1, kernel_size=4) 
                                              ## BATCH_SIZE=20
    self.relu = torch.nn.ReLU()
    self.fc = torch.nn.Linear(in_features=97*381, out_features=50)
    self.cross_entropy_loss = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

  def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, labels):
    output = self.roberta(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask) 
    x = output['last_hidden_state']
    x = torch.unsqueeze(x, 0)
    x = self.convlayer(x)
    x = self.relu(x)
    x = F.max_pool2d(x, kernel_size=4, stride=2)
    x = x.squeeze().flatten()
    x = self.fc(x)
    output = self.relu(x)
    crossent_loss = self.cross_entropy_loss(labels, output)
    return crossent_loss, output
  
  def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    input_ids = batch['text_input_ids']
    attention_mask = batch['text_attention_mask']

    l = batch['labels'].float()
    l = torch.tensor(l/torch.linalg.norm(l))

    labels = l # normalized labels in (0,1)
    labels_attention_mask = batch['labels_attention_mask']


    loss, outputs = self(
                         input_ids = input_ids,
                         attention_mask = attention_mask,
                         labels = labels
                         )
    self.log('train_loss', loss, prog_bar = True, logger = True)
    return loss

  def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx): 
    input_ids = batch['text_input_ids']
    attention_mask = batch['text_attention_mask']

    l = batch['labels'].float()
    l = torch.tensor(l/torch.linalg.norm(l))
    
    labels = l
    labels_attention_mask = batch['labels_attention_mask']

    loss, outputs = self(
                         input_ids = input_ids,
                         attention_mask = attention_mask,
                         labels = labels
                         )
    self.log('val_loss', loss, prog_bar = True, logger = True)
    return loss

  def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    input_ids = batch['text_input_ids']
    attention_mask = batch['text_attention_mask']
    
    l = batch['labels'].float()
    l = torch.tensor(l/torch.linalg.norm(l))
    
    labels = l
    labels_attention_mask = batch['labels_attention_mask']

    loss, outputs = self(
                         input_ids = input_ids,
                         attention_mask = attention_mask,
                         labels = labels
                         )
    self.log('test_loss', loss, prog_bar = True, logger = True)
    return loss

  def configure_optimizers(self):
    return AdamW(self.parameters(), lr=0.0001)
```

The training using `pl.Trainer` returns `ValueError: Expected input batch_size (20) to match target batch_size (50).`
I could not get the error.

Comment: Text summarisation is a seq2seq problem, what your doing is closer to classification. You can take a look at this https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/encoderdecoder.html, to make a custom encoder decoder model

Comment: If you have a time constraint, try using this library which wraps the transformers library https://simpletransformers.ai/docs/seq2seq-model/